# PDF to HTML in a nodejs application

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pdf, telegram

I'm trying to extract the content of a PDF to obtain the equivalent HTML.

I'm using Nodejs to do so (it's a telegram bot).

I googled for a while and I've been able to find only HTML to PDF things like using poppetteer and similar. Do you know something that does the exact reverse thing?

Ty in advance.

Comment: Why is extracting the content important for you? What do you do with the HTML afterwards? For a typical PDF there is no semantic information (no tables, no sentences, no headings, etc.)

Comment: The goal is to create an epub (that is basically an html page) from the pdf

Comment: Are you looking for Fixed layout EPUB, so it looks identical to the PDF source? Or you want reflowable HTML?

Comment: Nono, it's okay if I've to write the actual html (for the prototype I'll for <p> for content and some <h1/2> for titles

Comment: I don't follow. Perhaps you could update your question to give everyone more insight into what you are trying to accomplish (requirements+goals).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [pdfjs-dist](https://github.com/mozilla/pdfjs-dist).

I haven't used that library, but it seems to be the one to take you a bit closer to your objective. Also, as you probably already know, a PDF can contain anything: scanned text, photos, drawings, what not.

It is probably impossible to have a library that is able to extract all the info a human can extract from a PDF.

Comment: I will "scan" most of the time only text and maybe some images, not more. I'll check it out, thanks!

Comment: PDF.js is a PDF to HTML5 canvas viewer. How can it "extract the content of a PDF to obtain the equivalent HTML"?

Comment: I tried to use this but it's very "dumb", for some pdf it extracts letter by letter, for others it extracts well formed word but it's not "deterministic" and it's very hard to deal with it

Comment: This is most likely because of how the PDF graphic operations are written in the particular files you are testing. PDF is an immediate mode graphics engine, like OpenGL, and not a DOM like HTML/SVG. So most likely PDF.js is extracting the text as it is exactly written in the graphics stream.